# How to select elements in jQuery that are not children of particular element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have nested Masonry grids like this:

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="column">1</div> <!-- <- This one -->
    <div class="column">2</div> <!-- <- This one -->
    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="column">3</div>
        <div class="column">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="column">5</div> <!-- <- This one -->
        <div class="column">6</div> <!-- <- This one -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How to **select columns** which are not nested inside another Masonry grid. Result set would hold columns 1, 2, 5 and 6?

I have references to both masonry elements:

```
var parentMasonry;
var childMasonry;
var elementsOutsideChild = parentMasonry.find('.column').not( /* What here? Not children of another .masonry? */ );
/* Or select all than apply filter? What is best to do? */
```

Comment: Try `parentMasonry.find('>.column')`

Comment: Columns are not immediate children, they are nested inside dom tree.

Comment: You need to use filter (http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and pass there function which will check parents('.masonry') and you need count=1..

Comment: That also looked too complicated for me, I hoped there may be simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.masonry .column:not(.masonry .masonry .column)').css("color", "red");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5njactk/1/

Comment: Yes, I hoped to see this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is literally: I want "masonry columns", that are not "masonry masonry columns" :)

Answer (score 0):

The right solution would be to assign other classes to the nested divs

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="column">1</div>
    <div class="column">2</div>
    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="column col-exclude">3</div>
        <div class="column col-exclude">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="column">5</div>
        <div class="column">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so you can go with:

```
$('.masonry').find('.column').not('.col-exclude');
```

but i would try with this

`var elementsOutsideChild = parentMasonry.find('.column').not('.masonry')`

because if your parentMasonry reference is correct, you should be able to find the columns you need

I have tried another working solution, if you need

```
$('.masonry').find('.column').not('.masonry .masonry .column').each(function(){

    var that = $(this);
    that.css({"color":"blue"});

});
```

Comment: I would not like to add more classes, because this will be a Drupal output and I cannot know how many Masonry grids there will be and if they are nested or not. I would have to add unique classes to each grid.

Comment: Could the output have more levels of nestings? (eg. masonry -> masonry -> masonry)?

Comment: No, I don't think so, it could cause a headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elementsOutsideChild = parentMasonry.find('.column').not(function(){ return $(this).parents('.masonry').length !== 1 })
```

Comment: Guess this may help others, but for me TrueBlueAussie's answer is more acceptable. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, Will work with any level on nested columns

```
$('.masonry').find('.masonry').find('.column').addClass('nested');
var columns = $('.column').not('.nested');
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/tqn2kumc/

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, but I really do not need additional classes. Thank you for your time, hope this may help others.